# Why should we separate jsp scriptlet and jsp expression?

Tags: jsp

Why should we nest jsp expression inside a jsp scriptlet like the below
suppose state is true

```
if(state) { %>

    <%= "yes"%>

<%} else { %>

    <%= "no"%>

%<}%>
```

Comment: Now I got the answer. Scriptlet code is  inserted into the servlet directly without any change. So If we place any expression nested in scriptlet, it is a compile time error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<%= foo %>` means: evaluate foo, and print it to the JSP writer. So, if you want to do that inside a scriptlet, you simply need

```
<% out.print(foo); %>
```

Your above example can thus be written as

```
<%
if(state) {
    out.print("yes");
} else {
    out.print("no");
}
%>
```

That said, scriptlets shouldn't be used, at all, and for ages. Learn the [JSP EL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info), the [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info), and use other custom tags if needed. But don't use scriptlets.

If `state` was a page or request attribute, for example, the above code could be written as

```
${state ? "yes" : "no"}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Just for curiosity, why should we nest jsp expression inside jsp scriptlet. Cant we write it out side jsp scriptlet?

Comment: Isn't that what you asked in your question, and what I gave an answer to? If not, please explain what you mean. Show an example of what you would like to be able to do.

Comment: <%
if(state) {
    <%= "yes"%>
} else {
    <%= "no"%>
}
%>

Comment: Hi JB what is the problem if we write like the above?